# Using Getx Pages with Fixed Google NavBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-routes

I'm a newbie in flutter. I found that using getx routes (GetPages) instead of classic routes is very easy and manageble. In a same way I found google_nav_bar package is very easy and stylish. But my least attemp to use them together is a little bit complicated.

My first problem is I don't want to put appBar argument to Scaffold in every page file, and I'm wanting it to be on every page without reloading. Because I put the appBar argument to every single file and it's realoading itself and making distracting re-animations. How can I fix this problem? There are tons of tutorials on the internet but everyone making different things and some of them very difficult.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I was trying to learn a proper way of navigation between pages and there was a video called how to navigate properly in flutter. It was teaching this getx. You're a saver. I'll not use getx again.

Comment: Look for the many tutorials using "go router".  That seems to be the preferred router, since it is supported by the flutter core.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

if you use google nav bar in all pages then nav bar is re-animate otherwise you use navbar in only one page then it is not re-animated.

Comment: But I wanting it to be in every page.

Comment: please show me you code

Comment: [link](https://github.com/lawuysal/flutter_page_tests) here is my current situation. I'm not using Navigator.of(context) here. But I want to use it. How can I do it?